# php update image in sql. My problem is that when I added data it was 0 byte

Tags: javascript, php, sql, vue.js, file-upload

This is the code used to upload images using axios to the api and the PHP code used to receive uploaded images. I want to upload images and store them in the database. In my database the tea_license field is the image type data. Where do I need to modify my code? Please help me fix it. My problem is that when I added data it was 0 byte.

This is the axios code.

```
 async CRUDPersonal({ state, dispatch }) {
    try {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("CRUDPersonnel", JSON.stringify(state.InputPersonnel));
      formData.append("fileLicense", state.PersonnelImage.fileLicense);
      const response = await window.Axios.post(
        `${window.api}exec/CRUDPersonnel/`,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
          },
        }
      );
      await window.Swal.fire({
        position: "center",
        icon: response.data.type,
        title: response.data.alert,
        text: response.data.text,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 2000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
      });
      if (response.data.type == "success")
        await dispatch("ActionRead2/R_GET_Personnel", null, { root: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

This is the php code.

```
<?php   
    $json = json_decode($_POST['CRUDPersonnel'], true);
    $tea_id = $json['tea_id'];
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES["fileLicense"]["tmp_name"]);
    sql = "UPDATE personal_teacher_license SET tea_license='$fileContent' WHERE tea_id='$tea_id'";
    $this->SsDb->Query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Try and remove the `Content-Type` header. A multipart request needs the _boundary_ specified via this header as well - which axios should handle on its own, automatically.

Comment: This again. Where is `$this->SsDb` defined? `sql = "UPDATE ...` is missing a `$` for `$sql`

Comment: You really should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) when inserting user-defined data

Comment: Could you please add a code snippet of how you get the data from the HTML form into the state?